# How to move Image to position x, y coordinate with current scale and padding

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-photoview

I am using [Photoview](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView) Library in my project. I need to **setPadding** in Imageview with Zoom.

When I use with **left and top padding**, It working Perfectly. It also move image from left and top as I wish.

```
mPhotoView.setPadding(150, 150, 0, 0);
```

[image: image with left padding]

But, When I apply **right padding** and **bottom padding** , it apply padding but not automatically move from current place.

```
mPhotoView.setPadding(0, 0, 150, 150);     //Issue here.
```

[image: Image with right padding]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [**`requestLayout()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#requestLayout()) after setting padding in your `mPhotoView`

> public void requestLayout ()

- **Call this when something has changed which has invalidated the layout of this view.** This will schedule a layout pass of the view tree. This should not be called while the view hierarchy is currently in a layout pass (isInLayout(). If layout is happening, the request may be honored at the end of the current layout pass (and then layout will run again) or after the current frame is drawn and the next layout occurs.

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:onClick="ClickMe3"
        android:text="Remove Padding " />

    <com.github.chrisbanes.photoview.PhotoView
        android:id="@+id/photo_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:onClick="ClickMe"
        android:text="left and top " />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:onClick="ClickMe2"
        android:text="right and bottom " />


</RelativeLayout>
```

> Activity Code

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;


import com.github.chrisbanes.photoview.PhotoView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    PhotoView mPhotoView;
    boolean flag = true;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mPhotoView = (PhotoView) findViewById(R.id.photo_view);
        mPhotoView.setImageResource(R.drawable.dishu);

    }

    public void ClickMe(View view) {

        mPhotoView.setPadding(150, 150, 0, 0);
        mPhotoView.requestLayout();

    }

    public void ClickMe2(View view) {

        mPhotoView.setPadding(0, 0, 150, 150);
        mPhotoView.requestLayout();
    }

    public void ClickMe3(View view) {

        mPhotoView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
        mPhotoView.requestLayout();

    }


}
```

Please check the output of the above code https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=828XI6ydNdY

**UPDATE**

as per your below comment

> My ImageView with FItXY scaletype. When I apply your code , Not working. same result. It can't move automatic as left padding.

Actually Your padding Right and Bottom is working 
after setting padding you need to scroll your `mPhotoView`

Like below code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    PhotoView mPhotoView;
    RelativeLayout rootView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        rootView =  findViewById(R.id.rootView);
        mPhotoView = (PhotoView) findViewById(R.id.photo_view);

        mPhotoView.setImageResource(R.drawable.dishu);
    }

    public void Left_Top(View view) {
        mPhotoView.setPadding(150, 150, 0, 0);
        mPhotoView.requestLayout();
    }

    public void Right_Bottom(View view) {
        mPhotoView.setPadding(0, 0, 150, 150);
        mPhotoView.requestLayout();
        // after setting padding scroll your mPhotoView to bottom
        mPhotoView.scrollTo(150,150);
    }

    public void ClickMe3(View view) {
        mPhotoView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
        mPhotoView.requestLayout();
        mPhotoView.scrollTo(0,0);
    }


}
```

Comment: My ImageView with FItXY scaletype. When I apply your code , Not working. same result.
It can't move automatic as left padding.

Comment: @AbhayKoradiya it actually setting padding  after applying padding try to scroll image

Comment: Yes It scrolls Perfectly, even I don't write requestlayout.

Comment: But, I want effect like left padding (Auto scrolling).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184386/discussion-between-abhay-koradiya-and-nilesh-rathod).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use constraints, put it in a `ConstraintLayout` and then set the edges to 0, or set the Constraint to how much you want it to not shift.

https://medium.com/@eugenebrusov/using-of-constraintlayout-to-set-your-imageview-in-16-9-ratio-9979d53ba976

Answer (score 0):

You can use Parent Layout (`LinearLayout` or `FramLayout`)to apply your padding on  and put your `ImageView` in it so its work according your requirements.

OR

You can use `ScaleType` property so it can be manage in a smooth way.

Comment: I want to zoom Imageview with out of boundry. so it can't help me.